# Variance of normal distributed least squares estimation

Tags: normal-distribution, least-squares, variance

I'm using Least Squares Estimation to find the parameter $a$ in the formula $Y = a * X$ .

If $Y $ ~ $N(a * X, sigma)$, how can I calculate $sigma$?

I think $sigma$ is not the same as the variance of parameter $a$. 
I hope to hear your thoughts.

As seen in the picture below, this is the normal distribution I mean.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model is $Y \sim \mathcal{N}( a x, \sigma)$, where there's only one "parameter" (the slope $a$) to be **fitted** in the linear regression. The underlying population variance $\sigma^2$ is to be **estimated**.

Denote the observations as $y_i$ (for $i = 1,2,\ldots, n$) and the sample mean as $\bar{y} \equiv \frac1{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i~$. The observations are made at positions (horizontal coordinate) $x_i$ where the average coordinate is deonted $\bar{x} \equiv \frac1{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i~$.

**The data is NOT centered:  $~~\bar y \neq 0$ and $\bar x \neq 0$ in general.**

A commonly used unbiased estimator $\widehat{\sigma^2}$ is the following: (the hat indicates it is an estimator)

$$\widehat{\sigma^2} = \frac1{n - 1} \sum_{i=1}^n \Bigl[  (y_i - \widehat{a} \,x_i )^2 \Bigr] ~~,~~ \text{where}~~\widehat{a}\equiv \dfrac{~~\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i ~~}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} $$

This expression of $\widehat{\sigma^2}$ can be rewritten into several other forms, but none of them are really "shorter" or as intuitive as the original expression of plugging-in-the-MLE. Numerical stability of doing nested or iterated sum of squares is not really an issue in most applications.

If you find the relevant [wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Estimation) hard to digest, then maybe try some widely used textbooks like `An Introduction to Statistical Learning with R` [by James (and 3 other authors)](https://books.google.com.tw/books/about/An_Introduction_to_Statistical_Learning.html?id=at1bmAEACAAJ&redir_esc=y) or the book by [Weisberg](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=U7FZmOc0nM4C).

Note that if in the textbook you see the denominator $n-2$ in some places, it is because when there are two parameters to be fitted (the slope AND the intercept). Here the intercept is a known constant (zero) and there is only one parameter to be fitted. In wikipedia, this is denoted as $n-p$ where $p$ is the number of parameters to be fitted.

---

The above is the an unbiased estimator for the variance $\sigma^2$, and if you want the standard deviation $\sigma = \sqrt{ \sigma^2}$, you can directly take the square root of the above

$$\widehat{\sigma} = \sqrt{ \widehat{\sigma^2} }$$

The fact that this $\widehat{\sigma}$ would be [biased](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation#Bias_correction) is well-known and often NOT a deal breaker, depending on your application.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I already thought it would be something like this, but I wasn't able to find it anywhere on the Internet.

Comment: Why do you say $$RSS \equiv \sum_{i = 1}^n \left[ \left( y_i - \bar y \right)^2 \right]- \frac{ \left(\sum_{i = 1}^n \bigl[ ( x_i - \bar x )( y_i - \bar y ) \bigr] \right)^2 }{ \sum_{i = 1}^n \left[ (x_i - \bar x)^2 \right] }$$ ?

I find on the internet that $$RSS = \sum_{i = 1}^n (y_i - (a \times x_i ) ) ^2$$ and this gives me an answer that is more reliable

Comment: Where would you find the value of $a$ to plug in? It is exactly the quantity to be fitted. You need to make all your calculations from the observed data.

Comment: With the least squares method you know that $$a=\frac{\sum(x_i \times y_i)}{\sum(x_i^2)}$$

Comment: Exactly, so after you substitute that in, keeping in mind of some other identities, you'll get the same. Are you telling me that you get different values from the two?

Comment: Hmm okay.. I used both equations for RSS on a dataset, but the outcome is different. But thanks for your extra help!

Comment: Okay, I see what's going on here. I have to apologize: I have unintentionally assumed that your data is centered (that $\bar x = 0$). Centering $x_i$ is a common practice so much so that I forgot not everybody does that. My RSS reduces to your RSS after centering. In other words, your RSS (that "shorter" formula) is correct with the expression for $a$ you just typed in the comment.

Comment: I shall edit the answer post. It's a good thing that you double checked with me. Really sorry about that.

Comment: No problem at all!

Comment: i did it. n=1407 :)

Comment: @itry What did you do?

Comment: @itry I'm sorry that StackExchange by design is rather inconvenient for discussions. Please refrain from leaving comments on other people's post in the future (this is generally frowned upon, NOT in particular my personal rule). If you want further conversation (like double checking you answer) you can restore that post of yours temporarily and we can talk there. `MathFun123` I'm sorry that to you this seems coming out of nowhere.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin its not that big of a deal